# What scriptures mention the all-consuming eternal fire burning North of the Himalayas?

Tags: mahabharata, rig-veda, vishnu-purana, aitareya-brahmana

If you've read the Vishnu Purana, then you're probably familiar with the story of how Vyasa's father Parashara, upon learning that his father Shakti had been killed by the Rakshasa Kalmashapada, decided to perform a Yagna to kill all the Rakshasas in the world.  But then he was persuaded not to carry it out, and his decision to spare the Rakshasas was rewarded with a boon that gave him the knowledge needed to narrate the Vishnu Purana, as described in the [first chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp035.htm) of the Vishnu Purana.

What's not as well-known, however, is what happened in the aftermath of the aborted Yagna.  Here is what [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01184.htm) of the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata says:

> Thus addressed by Pulastya, as also by the intelligent Vasishtha, that mighty Muni--the son of Saktri then brought that sacrifice to an end. And the Rishi cast the fire that he had ignited for the purpose of the Rakshasas' sacrifice into the deep woods on the north of the Himavat. And that fire may be seen to this day consuming Rakshasas and trees and stones in all seasons.

My question is, what scriptures describe this fire to the North of the Himalayas, which can be seen "to this day"?  Of course "this day" was 5000 years ago, but the way it's described it sounds like an eternal flame.

Now Hindu scripture says a variety of odd things about the land on the other side on the Himalayas, often called the land of the Uttarakurus.  It's often referred to as a "land of the gods".  In [this chapter](http://tinyurl.com/ndagybv) of the Aitareya Brahmana of the Rig Veda, Atyarati promises to give the Earth to Vasishta as soon as he conquers it, but then he refuses to give it because he hasn't conquered Uttarakuru yet. Vasishta curses him, because Uttarakuru is the land of the gods and thus unconquerable, so Atyarati has tricked him.  I may post a question about Uttarakuru later.

But in any case, are there any other scriptures that discuss the all-consuming fire set by Parashara North of the Himalayas?

Comment: [Chapter 61 of Matysa Purana](http://www.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/matsya-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-61/topic-1) do discuss fire which burnt Rakshasa but it doesn't say anything about location.

Comment: Could this be another natural eternal flame like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baba_Gurgur#Eternal_Fire) which is recorded to be about 2500 years old ?